# why am i getting not applicable for the arguments on javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, openfire, smack

I am making a chat client with smack. So after logging in I retrieve the roster into my javafx app. In order to listen if my buddies are available I tried to use a listener like this:

```
            rosterList.addListener(new ChangeListener<ObservableList<RosterDTO>>(){

                @Override
                public void changed(
            ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<RosterDTO>> observable,
                                ObservableList<RosterDTO> oldValue,
                                ObservableList<RosterDTO> newValue) {
                            rosterList = loginManager.getXmppManager().displayBuddyList();
                            System.out.println("x----" + rosterList.toString()); 

        }
```

So, after I entered my code, eclipse returns:

> The method addListener(ListChangeListener) in the
>   type ObservableList is not applicable for the arguments
>   (new   ChangeListener>(){})

Why is that happening? How should my listener be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) is not a [ListChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.html).

[ObservableList.addListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addListener%28javafx.collections.ListChangeListener%29) requires a ListChangeListener as it's parameter.

The [JavaFX collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm) details how to use ListChangeListeners.